# Never is not provided to BlocBuilder<SocialCubit, SocialStates>. Context used for Bloc retrieval must be a descendant of BlocProvider

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to make a social media app and when setup my layout contains bottom Nav bar and screens also my cubit is ok and the code in the main is ok I tried to change bottom Nav to Text and the problem solved I had a problem with getting Bloc from child widget and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
how can I got this error any one can help ?

```
class SocialLayout extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return BlocConsumer<SocialCubit , SocialStates>
        (listener: (context,state){},
        builder: (context,state)
        {
          var cubit= SocialCubit.get(context);

          return  Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title:   Text('News Feed',),
            ),
            body: cubit.screens[cubit.currentIndex],
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              currentIndex: cubit.currentIndex,
              onTap: (index){
                cubit.changeBottomNav(index);

              },
              items:   [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(IconBroken.Home,),label: "Home"),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(IconBroken.Chat,),label: "Chats"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(IconBroken.Setting,),label: "Settings"),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(IconBroken.User,),label: "Users"),

              ],
            ),
          );
    }
    );
}
}
//cubit 
class SocialCubit extends Cubit<SocialStates> {
  SocialCubit() : super(SocialInitialState());
static SocialCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);
 SocialUserModel ? socialUserModel;
void getUserData() {
   uId = CacheHelper.getData(key: 'uId');
    emit(SocialGetUserLoadingState());
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uId).get().then((value) {
      socialUserModel = SocialUserModel.fromJson(value.data());
      print(socialUserModel.toString());

      emit(SocialGetUserSuccessState());
    })
        .catchError((error) {
          print(error.toString());
          emit(SocialGetUserErrorState(error.toString()));
    });
  }
 int currentIndex =0;
 List<Widget>screens =[
    Feeds(),
    Chats(),
    Users(),
    Setting(),
 ];
 void changeBottomNav(int index)
 {
   currentIndex = index;
   emit(SocialChangeBottomNav());
 }
}
//main
void main() async
  SimpleBlocObserver();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  DioHelper.init();
  await CacheHelper.init();

  bool ? isDarkMode = CacheHelper.getData(key: 'isDarkMode');

  Widget widget;

  uId = CacheHelper.getData(key: 'uId');

if(uId != null)
  {
    widget = SocialLayout();
  }
else{
  widget=SocialLoginScreen();
}
  runApp(MyApp(isDarkMode, widget ,token ));
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    bool ? isDarkMode;
    late final Widget startWidget;
    String? token;



  MyApp(this.isDarkMode,this.startWidget, String? token, {Key? key}) : super(key: key) ;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [

        BlocProvider( create: (BuildContext context)  => AppCubit()..changeAppMode(fromShared: isDarkMode,),

        ),



        BlocProvider( create: (BuildContext context)  => SocialCubit()..getUserData(),
        ),

    ],
      child: BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
        listener: (context, state){},
        builder: (context ,state){
          return MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                themeMode:  AppCubit.get(context).isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.light: ThemeMode.dark,
            home: AnimatedSplashScreen(
              splash: SplashScreen(),
              nextScreen: startWidget,
              splashIconSize: 700,

              animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
              splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
            ),
            theme: MyTheme.lightTheme,
            darkTheme: MyTheme.darkTheme,
                 builder: BotToastInit(),
                 navigatorObservers: [BotToastNavigatorObserver()],


              );
            },




      ),
    );
  }
}

*Invalid argument(s): Never is not provided to BlocBuilder<SocialCubit, SocialStates>. Context used for Bloc retrieval must be a descendant of BlocProvider.
```

Comment: Where did you add your bloc provider? Can you add your code blocks?

Comment: main added please check it

Comment: also I added a blocProvider in my layout screen but same issue still exist

Comment: First of all, you can't access 'AppCubit' should wrap with Builder widget

Answer (score 0):

Solved by remove unused bloc packages from pubsbec.yaml file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).